# Trying to get volume on IPHONE to communicate with Raspberry pi over blue tooth

Tags: raspbian

I have my iPhone connected via bluetooth to my raspberry pi, and now I am trying to figure out how to receive the volume control from my IPHONE, I assume I need to read  and write attributes, but I am not seeing any. Yes I did read the previous questions on this topic and they don't seem to address the specific question.

For example I tried doing this

[arthur reisman’s iPhone]# list-attributes
[arthur reisman’s iPhone]#

and nothing returns at all no attributes , I would  assume volume setting was an attribute if not where is it.